# CMake C++. OStream : is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, cmake

So, this is my first time using CMake, but this is very odd error at least in my opinion. Anything that i use in the C++ Standard Library throws an error, currently i have 100+ errors because of this. Online i read it has something to do with the fact that my code is being compiled as 'C', although i do not know how to force C++.

This is my current CMakeLists:

```
project(Dynamik CXX)

if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /DSFML_STATIC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP /EHsc /wd4244 /wd4996 ")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /DNDEBUG /MT /MP /GS- /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Oy /arch:SSE /fp:fast /Zi")
    set(CMAKE_LIB_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_LIB_LINKER_FLAGS} /OPT:REF /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

else() # Most likely gcc or clang
    if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "4.7")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    endif()

    if (BUILD_COVERAGE AND "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
      set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
    endif()

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "-g")
endif()

# Lets LOAD app our headers!
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS ${Dynamik_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)

# Lets LOAD app our sources!
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS
    ${Dynamik_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
    ${Dynamik_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c
)

#define the library
add_library(Dynamik STATIC ${HDRS} ${SRCS})

#Look for the packages we need

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# GLEW
INCLUDE(${Dynamik_CMAKE_DIR}../CMake/FindGLEW.cmake)

# SDL2
INCLUDE(${Dynamik_CMAKE_DIR}../CMake/FindSDL2.cmake)

# Define the include DIR's 
include_directories(
    ${Dynamik_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Here's a few of the errors:

```
2>  DynamikError.cpp
2>  FileUtils.cpp
2>  FpsLimiter.cpp
2>  InputManager.cpp
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\MathFunc.h(10): error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(126): error C2039: 'fmaf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(126): error C3861: 'fmaf': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(131): error C2039: 'fma' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(131): error C3861: 'fma': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(136): error C2039: 'fmal' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(136): error C3861: 'fmal': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(154): error C2039: 'remquof' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(154): error C3861: 'remquof': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(159): error C2039: 'remquo' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(159): error C3861: 'remquo': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(164): error C2039: 'remquol' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(164): error C3861: 'remquol': identifier not found (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'abs' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'abs' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2039: 'fabs' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2873: 'fabs' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2039: 'modf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2873: 'modf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'acosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'acosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'asinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'asinf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'atanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'atanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'atan2f' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec2.h(33): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'atan2f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'ceilf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'ceilf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'cosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'cosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'coshf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'coshf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'expf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'expf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2039: 'fabsf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec3.h(35): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2873: 'fabsf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2039: 'floorf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2873: 'floorf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2039: 'ostream' : is not a member of 'std' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2039: 'fmodf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2873: 'fmodf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2433: 'Dynamik::ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2039: 'frexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2873: 'frexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2039: 'ldexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2873: 'ldexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2039: 'logf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\Vec4.h(36): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(36): error C2873: 'logf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2039: 'log10f' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2873: 'log10f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2039: 'modff' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2873: 'modff' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>f:\dynamik-cmake\dynamik\MathFunc.h(10): error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\DynamikError.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2039: 'powf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(37): error C2873: 'powf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(38): error C2039: 'sinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (F:\Dynamik-CMake\Dynamik\FileUtils.cpp)
```

Any help to resolve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code you're trying to compile? Looks like you did not include the correct libraries.

Comment: Uhh.... Its a lot of code. I have the Visual Studio project on github if that would help you.

Comment: The definitions you're adding to the compiler's commandline with `add_definitions` are clearly for GCC. Try removing them when compiling with MSVC, and see if it helps. As a side note, you should really be adding your own flags to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` - `add_definitions` is meant for compile-time definitions, not compiler flags.

Comment: O and it should but noted i am compiling a library.

Comment: @ZakStrange - in that case, I'm out of ideas given the current information.

Comment: Is it your project or should it compile, because it is a bigger project by some group. What is line 33 of Vec2.h and what are the libraries included by this header?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar is there any other information i could give you to help solve this problem?

Comment: Like 33 of Vec2 is : 'friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const vec2& vector);' and all it includes is ostream

Comment: could you provide the content of FileUtils.cpp or link to the project on github?

Comment: @user3188346 Yes i can give you the github link (Please note that github currently does not have the CMake build, but if you would like i can put it on a new branch): github.com/ZakStrange/Dynamik

Comment: You use the header: Math.h and due to the fact that windows is case insensitive it clashes with math.h from standard library. What is more: Do not use GLOB_RECURSE to obtain list of source files, this is very lazy and cmake does not guarantee recompilation will work as you expect. Use set and list the files.

Comment: Okay thank you I will change the global recurse when I get home and change the Math.h name then test. Expect results in the next few hours

Comment: MSVC. Probably not the smartest idea

Comment: @user3188346 I did everything you said and the build works!